# When using Azure DevOps CI/CD for a Linux web app how can I zip and publish the build artifact as a zip file only instead of copying to directory

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-web-app-service, azure-webapps

[Per these instructions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/ecosystems/javascript?view=azure-devops) I am creating devops project integrating CI/CD for a Linux Web App.

Here is my initial Pipelines pipelines/build job

```yaml
trigger:
- master

pool:
  vmImage: 'ubuntu-latest'

steps:
- task: NodeTool@0
  inputs:
    versionSpec: '12.x'
  displayName: 'Install Node.js'

- script: |
    npm install -g @angular/cli
    npm install
    npm run build:ssr
  displayName: 'npm install and build'

- task: CopyFiles@2
  inputs:
    Contents: |
      dist/** 
      node_modules/**
      package.json
    TargetFolder: '$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)'
    CleanTargetFolder: true
    OverWrite: true

- task: PublishBuildArtifacts@1
  inputs:
    PathtoPublish: '$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)'
    ArtifactName: 'drop'
    publishLocation: 'Container'
```

When because the `CopyFiles@2` task there are 65000 files copying over to the directory to be published in the following `PublishBuildArtifacts@1` task.

Because of this I thought I could add the `Artifact` task after the copy task and this would produce a `.zip` file and make the deployment more efficient and many times over faster.

However, this was not the case and all it did was serve to zip the folder up, un-zip the folder and proceed to do the same individual file processing like show below. At the time it took me to write this post it has been about 14 minutes and this is how far it has gotten.

```
Async Command Start: Upload Artifact
Uploading 65244 files
Total file: 65244 ---- Processed file: 69 (0%)
Total file: 65244 ---- Processed file: 200 (0%)
Total file: 65244 ---- Processed file: 333 (0%)
Total file: 65244 ---- Processed file: 460 (0%)
Total file: 65244 ---- Processed file: 603 (0%)
Total file: 65244 ---- Processed file: 746 (1%)
Total file: 65244 ---- Processed file: 884 (1%)
Total file: 65244 ---- Processed file: 1026 (1%)
Total file: 65244 ---- Processed file: 1142 (1%)
Total file: 65244 ---- Processed file: 1268 (1%)
Total file: 65244 ---- Processed file: 1365 (2%)
Total file: 65244 ---- Processed file: 1509 (2%)
Total file: 65244 ---- Processed file: 1672 (2%)
Total file: 65244 ---- Processed file: 1839 (2%)
Total file: 65244 ---- Processed file: 1993 (3%)
Total file: 65244 ---- Processed file: 2188 (3%)
Total file: 65244 ---- Processed file: 2362 (3%)
Total file: 65244 ---- Processed file: 2540 (3%)
Total file: 65244 ---- Processed file: 2701 (4%)
Total file: 65244 ---- Processed file: 2854 (4%)
Total file: 65244 ---- Processed file: 3051 (4%)
Total file: 65244 ---- Processed file: 3256 (4%)
Total file: 65244 ---- Processed file: 3459 (5%)
Total file: 65244 ---- Processed file: 3656 (5%)
Total file: 65244 ---- Processed file: 3836 (5%)
Total file: 65244 ---- Processed file: 4025 (6%)
Total file: 65244 ---- Processed file: 4196 (6%)
Total file: 65244 ---- Processed file: 4385 (6%)
Total file: 65244 ---- Processed file: 4545 (6%)
Total file: 65244 ---- Processed file: 4694 (7%)
Total file: 65244 ---- Processed file: 4864 (7%)
Total file: 65244 ---- Processed file: 5044 (7%)
Total file: 65244 ---- Processed file: 5253 (8%)
Total file: 65244 ---- Processed file: 5422 (8%)
Total file: 65244 ---- Processed file: 5620 (8%)
```

Is there a way to do what I am looking for? Should I not copy and then zip but rather just zip? Is this because it is the Linux pathway vs the Windows pathway.

As of now this would not be possible to utilize as it would take an hour for a deployment.

Here is the task for the `Deploy Azure App Service` task

```yaml
steps:
- task: AzureRmWebAppDeployment@4
  displayName: 'Deploy Azure App Service'
  inputs:
    azureSubscription: '$(Parameters.ConnectedServiceName)'
    appType: '$(Parameters.WebAppKind)'
    WebAppName: '$(Parameters.WebAppName)'
    packageForLinux: '$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/**/**/*.zip'
    RuntimeStack: 'NODE|12-lts'
    StartupCommand: '$(Parameters.StartupCommand)'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can archive a specific folder into a zip, 7z, or tar archive. Then you can publish only the archive as an artifact from the pipeline. Here's an example of archiving the `dist`, `node_modules`, and `package.json` content to a zip and then publishing it as an artifact.

The important bit here is `replaceExistingArchive: false` on the Archive tasks, this will add each folder/file to the archive. The one exception being if you archive to a compressed TAR file, those are always fully replaced. ([Source](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-devops-docs/issues/1213#issuecomment-514605464))

Also the Artifact task just publishes the files so they are acccessible outside of the pipeline, it doesn't compress them into an archive.

```yaml
steps:
- task: ArchiveFiles@2
  displayName: 'Archive Dist Folder'
  inputs:
    rootFolderOrFile: 'dist'
    includeRootFolder: false
    archiveFile: '$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)/archive.zip'
    replaceExistingArchive: false
- task: ArchiveFiles@2
  displayName: 'Archive node_modules Folder'
  inputs:
    rootFolderOrFile: 'node_modules'
    includeRootFolder: false
    archiveFile: '$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)/archive.zip'
    replaceExistingArchive: false
- task: ArchiveFiles@2
  displayName: 'Archive package.json File'
  inputs:
    rootFolderOrFile: 'package.json'
    includeRootFolder: false
    archiveFile: '$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)/archive.zip'
    replaceExistingArchive: false
- task: PublishBuildArtifacts@1
  inputs:
    PathtoPublish: '$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)/archive.zip'
    ArtifactName: 'drop'
    publishLocation: 'Container'
```

I wanted to update this answer to include my final solution that worked as of 4/17/2020. Remember things are always changing in the cloud space but as of now this is a full on solution.

1. Here are my pipeline build steps:

```yaml
steps:
- task: NodeTool@0
  inputs:
    versionSpec: '12.x'
  displayName: 'Install Node.js'

- script: |
    npm install -g @angular/cli
    npm install
    npm run build:ssr
  displayName: 'npm install and build'

- task: ArchiveFiles@2
  displayName: 'Archive dist Folder'
  inputs:
    rootFolderOrFile: 'dist'
    includeRootFolder: true
    archiveType: 'zip'
    archiveFile: '$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)/archive.zip'
    replaceExistingArchive: false

- task: ArchiveFiles@2
  displayName: 'Archive node_modules Folder'
  inputs:
    rootFolderOrFile: 'node_modules'
    includeRootFolder: true
    archiveType: 'zip'
    archiveFile: '$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)/archive.zip'
    replaceExistingArchive: false

- task: ArchiveFiles@2
  displayName: 'Archive package.json File'
  inputs:
    rootFolderOrFile: 'package.json'
    includeRootFolder: false
    archiveType: 'zip'
    archiveFile: '$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)/archive.zip'
    replaceExistingArchive: false

- task: PublishBuildArtifacts@1
  inputs:
    PathtoPublish: '$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)/archive.zip'
    ArtifactName: 'drop'
    publishLocation: 'Container'
```

2. Here is my deploy step in the Releases part of the pipeline when using the task `Deploy Azure App Service`.

```yaml
steps:
- task: AzureRmWebAppDeployment@4
  displayName: 'Deploy Azure App Service'
  inputs:
    azureSubscription: '$(Parameters.ConnectedServiceName)'
    appType: '$(Parameters.WebAppKind)'
    WebAppName: '$(Parameters.WebAppName)'
    packageForLinux: '$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/**/**/*.zip'
    RuntimeStack: 'NODE|12-lts'
    StartupCommand: '$(Parameters.StartupCommand)'
```

For some reason the yaml says that I have a lot of undefined system variables but that is not true because A. it works and B. I believe that are from your subscription and on the server system.

Lastly make sure to create the proper PM2 start command for your express server or universal angular app server implementation. This is found in the azure portal
`npm run serve:ssr`

Remember using npm run is for Linux servers as Microsoft Windows uses node run

Comment: that seems to work well but the App service deploy is now failing giving this return 2020-04-17T17:36:45.2854876Z Package deployment using ZIP Deploy initiated.
2020-04-17T17:38:52.6220739Z ##[error]Failed to deploy web package to App Service.
2020-04-17T17:38:52.6232436Z ##[error]Error: Error: Failed to deploy web package to App Service. Conflict (CODE: 409)
2020-04-17T17:38:54.0408649Z ##[warning]Error: Failed to update deployment history. Error: Bad Request (CODE: 400)

Comment: im going to post my Deploy Azure App Service task in the OP

Comment: ok so the changes I made instead of drop drop i did **/**/*.zip and that worked. here is my final issue I believe. so they way that is bundling everything now is taking everything from the folder and unbundling it out of the node_modules folder. same thing with what was in the dist folder. How can I maintain integrity. I will give it a shot but any advice is appreciated

Comment: @ChristianMatthew Not 100% on this, but you can try flipping `includeRootFolder: true` In my pipeline I wanted it flat, so that setting is `false` for me.

Comment: Yes that is what I did awesome. So MY GUY you are the man I will buy you a beer when I see you!!! thanks you ended my 3 days of misery. Ahhh god bless you. Thank YOU. I hope this helps someone else. I am going to edit your answer to give my final solution